# How to send messages to group chat using ejabber server with strophe library?

Tags: reactjs, ejabberd, strophe

While implementing chat in react web app using XMPP, the issue I've faced is storing sent data in Mysql DB end from Mnesia.
I used the strophe library for this to implement chat part in the web environment.
I am totally new to this chat server.

Here the workflow I'm following
1. Connection and authenticating to a ejabber server.
2. Creating a muc_room with some users.
3. I'm trying to send a message to the already created group, Here I designed the serve like it will store the messages to archive table in MySQL from Mnesia DB.
4. Finally, I want to get all the rosters list.

But I am facing a struggle in 3rd point I can't see the sent message from my end to the created group in **archive table** and I think it stored temporarily in Mnesia DB.

Please refer the pasted code regarding sendmessage,

```
var messagetype = (type) ? type : 'chat';
    var reply;
    if (messagetype === 'groupchat') {
        reply = window.$msg({
            to: messgeTo,
            from: connection.jid,
            type: messagetype,
            id: connection.getUniqueId()
        }).c("body", {xmlns: window.Strophe.NS.CLIENT}).t(message);
    }
    else {
        reply = window.$msg({to: messgeTo,
            from: connection.jid,
            type: messagetype
        }).c("body", {xmlns: window.Strophe.NS.CLIENT}).t(message);
    }
    connection.send(reply.tree());
    console.log('I sent ' + messgeTo + ': ' + message, reply.tree());
```

Please, try to give any ideas to fix this issue.

```
        /* Edited code */
    connection.muc.join(messageTo, messageTo.split('@')[0], function(st) {
            console.log(st, 'status');
        });
            if (messagetype === 'groupchat') {
                reply = window.$msg({
                    to: messageTo,
                    from: connection.jid,
                    type: messagetype,
                    id: connection.getUniqueId()
                }).c("body").t(message).up()
                .c('request', {'xmlns': window.Strophe.NS.RECEIPTS});
            } else {
                reply = window.$msg({to: messa`enter code here`geTo,
                    from: connection.jid,
                    type: messagetype
                }).c("body").t(message).up()
        }
        connection.send(reply.tree());
        console.log('I sent ' + messageTo + ': ' + message, reply.tree());
```

Before sending message to a chat group I've joined the muc room. After that prepared the message content and sent it.

Comment: Have you fixed this yet?

Comment: yup, It is fixed. Before sending message to group-chat, I used muc.join() to join the group. Please refer the edited code above to see the difference